# How to scrape football results from livescores?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-3.4, urllib

I have this project am working on using python 3.4. I want to scrape livescore.com for football scores (result) e.g getting all the scores of the day (England 2-2 Norway, France 2-1 Italy, etc). I am building it with python 3.4, windows 10 64bit os.

I have tried two ways this are the codes:

```
import bs4 as bs
import urllib.request

sauce = urllib.request.urlopen('http://www.livescore.com/').read()
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(sauce,'lxml')

for div in soup.find_all('div', class_='container'):
    print(div.text)
```

When I run this code a box pup's up saying:

> IDLE's subprocess didn't make connection. Either IDLE can't start a subprocess or firewall software is blocking the connection.

I decided to write another one this is the code:

```
# Import Modules
import urllib.request
import re

# Downloading Live Score XML Code From Website and reading also
xml_data = urllib.request.urlopen('http://static.cricinfo.com/rss/livescores.xml').read()

# Pattern For Searching Score and link
pattern = "<item>(.*?)</item>"

# Finding Matches
for i in re.findall(pattern, xml_data, re.DOTALL):
    result = re.split('<.+?>',i)
    print (result[1], result[3]) # Print Score
```

And I got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Bright\Desktop\live_score.py", line 12, in <module>
   for i in re.findall(pattern, xml_data, re.DOTALL):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\re.py", line 206, in findall
    return _compile(pattern, flags).findall(string)
TypeError: can't use a string pattern on a bytes-like object
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On your first example - the site is loading its content by heavy javascript so I suggest using selenium in fetching the source.

Your code should look like this:

```
import bs4 as bs
from selenium import webdriver

url = 'http://www.livescore.com/'
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get(url)
sauce = browser.page_source
browser.quit()
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(sauce,'lxml')

for div in soup.find('div', attrs={'data-type': 'container'}).find_all('div'):
    print(div.text)
```

For the second example, it regular expression engine returns an error because the `read()` function from your requests gives byte data type, "re" only accepts strings or unicode. So you just t have toypecast xml_data to str.

This is the modified code:

```
for i in re.findall(pattern, str(xml_data), re.DOTALL):
    result = re.split('<.+?>',i)
    print (result[1], result[3]) # Print Score
```

Comment: Hi @Chad I uploaded a screenshot of the page I want to scrape when I did inspect element using chrome, and I marked the Div tags and the website layout with colors according to where the div is targeted please help me and review the code (The first Code)  thanks

Comment: Hi! I edited my answer, please take a look. Let me know if you need clarifications. If that solved your concern, please mark it as answer. Thanks!

Comment: Hi @Chad i uploaded an image of the error i got from running the code you added, the first code  and please give me your facebook info so i can add and this is mine brightgodwin47@yahoo.com thanks

Comment: 1. pip install chromedriver
2. update code:
`browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\Python34\chromedriver-Windows')`

Comment: Please I had that to use selenium the I need to open the page first before it will work

Comment: And please add me on facebook or Whatsapp my mobile number is +2347089544619 please